# Unexpected end of format string error message

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I get this message

```
Warning <100>: Unexpected end of format string in format string at <1>  
            write (iout,'(i5,4x,i4,6x,15(a25,1x)') i, ksum, temp (1:isum)  
                       1
```

several times when compiling code written in Fortran90 (not by me). Here is an example of the code with the error:

```
if (isum > 0) then
          ksum = ksum + isum
          write (iout,'(i5,4x,i4,6x,15(a25,1x)') i, ksum, temp (1:isum)
          if (ksum == NSPECIES - NotPhotographed) go to 5
        endif
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am assuming the `1` is indicating the location of the error, but I havn't been able to discover how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you're missing a closing parenthesis in there between the `'`s.